# How to upgrade a 2009 MacBook Pro from 10.11.6 to 10.12?

Tags: macbook-pro, safari, macos

I have a 2009 MacBook Pro running OS X 10.11.6 "El Capitan". Can I upgrade to macOS "Sierra" 10.12, and if so, how? I can't find it on the App Store.

Answer (score 2):

The newest version that is **Apple** supported for a **2009 MacBook Pro** is **OS X 10.11.6**; however, there is a *third-party patcher*, [macOS Sierra Patcher Tool for Unsupported Macs](http://dosdude1.com/sierrapatch.html), by [*dosdude1*](http://dosdude1.com) if you want to go that route.

If you want to go the *dosdude1* route, you can get the **InstallOS.dmg** *file* for **macOS Sierra** from a link in [How to upgrade to macOS Sierra](https://support.apple.com/HT208202), under step **4 Download macOS Sierra** where it says:

> If you still need macOS Sierra, use this link: [Download macOS Sierra](http://updates-http.cdn-apple.com/2019/cert/061-39476-20191023-48f365f4-0015-4c41-9f44-39d3d2aca067/InstallOS.dmg). A file named InstallOS.dmg will download to your Mac.

<sub>Note: I am not affiliated with dosdude1, and only know about this from seeing it on the Internet.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

The maximum supported OS for all of the MacBook Pros released in 2009 is OS X El Capitan 10.11.6 (15G31).

So your model of MacBook Pro can not be officially upgraded to macOS Sierra 10.12.